# members only products

Tags: users, search

i'm looking to setup a website and would like to know if the Wordpress platform can accomodate these requirements.
I need a members only area and I need the ability to sell certain products ONLY to members. I would also need the ability to search for products (range is around 150 items) and have public clients able to only search items that are available to them. I have searched other platforms and their search functions could not discriminate between member and public ... and the public were able to locate member only products and place orders for them (which totally defeats the purpose of having member only items).

Comment: Please share us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on your child theme’s functions.php file..

```
//Hide for non-logged-in users (public visitors)
function bp_logged_out_page_template_redirect() { 

    if( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'members' ) 
        || is_page( 'activity' ) 
        || bp_is_user() ) 
    { 
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/register/' ) ); exit(); 
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bp_logged_out_page_template_redirect' );
```

The above snippet will do:
•IF the user is not logged-in..
•AND the page name is ‘members’ OR ‘activity’ OR bp-profile-page..
•THEN it will redirect to REGISTER page.

Ref: https://vvcares.com/w/wordpress-hide-pages-for-non-logged-in-users/